# How to show a part of html?

Tags: flutter

I want to put a part of html in a flutter page,but it could not show correctly.

This is my String of html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
String str = <p style="text-align: center;"><u>说法司法考试满分多少积</u></p>;
widget build(BuildContext context){Html(data:sta)}
```

but "text-aligin:center" does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the html parsing code for flutter_html you will see [here](https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/blob/master/lib/html_parser.dart#L160-L171) that text-align is not one of the supported implementations of html parsing. You could go in and add your own switch statement to the parser for your text-align or use some of the existing properties there to find out which tags you need to use. For instance searching for "align" in the source shows that using a '< tr >' tag places content in the middle of the provided Row, that might work, but just search through there.

The [official Flutter WebView](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) package has been created and is in a developer preview. It's not stable yet, and also doesn't allow for data to be passed through to it, only url navigation but it makes use of the actual web views. Check up on its current state maybe it's at a point where you can use it to render html properly.

Comment: I made a PR for official Flutter WebView to display HTML string  https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1312

Comment: @TruongSinh nice.